# Which is deemed better practice? Standard and/or clause or case then?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following two statements both have negligible execution times over a relatively large table. Subsequently I was wondering which would be deemed better practice? Personally I think that the 'case' (option 2) statement reads a lot easier to somebody who make look at this a year from now however option 1 seems a lot cleaner.

**Option #1:**

```
select *
from imaginarytable
where   1=1
    and (@section_name = 'ALL' or upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name))
```

**Option #2:**

```
select *
from imaginarytable
where   1=1
    and upper(section_name)=
        case when @section_name <> 'ALL' 
             then upper(@section_name
             else upper(section_name)
        end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I cannot imagine anyone finding the `CASE` version more clear. The first option is basic boolean logic, which every CS student learns and with which we all should find very comfortable.

Plus, I'm not even sure your 2 expressions are equivalent, in part because the `CASE` expression is basically incomprehensible.

Comment: I don't think they are equivalent either.

Comment: Another, unrelated point. SQL string comparisons are, by default, case insensitive. So the `upper` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. End result that I've used is:

and (@section_name = 'ALL' 
 or (@section_name <> 'ALL' and upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name))